# User entity gets incorrectly updated when i try to update another entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine, entity

I am trying to create a post on symfony (3.3) but I am having a problem and I dont know why,
Just if you are ROLE_ADMIN you can create a post, well the problem is that when I do symfony say

```
An exception occurred while executing 'UPDATE login SET password = ? WHERE id = ?' with params [null, 1]:
```

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'password' cannot be null

and I am not trying to update nothing for my entity user
My entities are
User (id,password,email,token,role,active) is my user provider
Usuario(name,last_name,created_date,social_login,User ->here is the reference to the table user MenyToOne  )
Post (title,content,shor_content,etc and Usuario,(ManyToOne))
I dont know if this can help but i dont know why when i try to create a post i get this error, 
Any idea?

Comment: Show the code that causes this error please!

Comment: Can you show Your Entity?

Comment: probaby an incorrect 'cascade persist' annotation, but as stated above,  show your code

Comment: Maybe your post request is wrong. You send a null data. But we can't help you much without code

Answer (score 0):

Hey i think i know what you meant. Had same issue second ago. The answer is to flush just post

```
$user = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
$post->setUser($user);
$this->em->persist($post); 
$this->em->flush($post); // make sure you put $post as parameter
```